# Simple WebView with embedded videos (Youtube, Vimeo Etc...), and some more features

Tags: java, android, xml

I tried to create a very simple Webview with embedded video's in it, that can change to vertical and not reset to its default when changed to vertical or vice versa, even tho its working just fine I'm still feeling like the site is a bit heavy (its a simple wordpress website with some textual data and images, nothing heavy) and loading is slow from time to time. I want to publish it on GIthub as a simple example for a good basic Webview for people to use but I want it to look sharp and suitable for high traffic of users. any advice is more then welcome.

MainActivity.java

```
package il.co.streamerapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private FrameLayout customViewContainer;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback customViewCallback;
    private View mCustomView;
    private myWebChromeClient mWebChromeClient;
    private myWebViewClient mWebViewClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        customViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);

        mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
        webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.streamer.co.il");
        } else {
            webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState )
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        webView.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public boolean inCustomView() {
        return (mCustomView != null);
    }

    public void hideCustomView() {
        mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        webView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        if (inCustomView()) {
            hideCustomView();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

            if (inCustomView()) {
                hideCustomView();
                return true;
            }

            if ((mCustomView == null) && webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view,CustomViewCallback callback) {

            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null) {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }
            mCustomView = view;
            webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.addView(view);
            customViewCallback = callback;
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView() {
            super.onHideCustomView();    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            if (mCustomView == null)
                return;

            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            customViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            customViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            customViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

            mCustomView = null;
        }
    }

    class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/customViewContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidMenifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="il.co.streamerapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Btw, does anyone know why some devices delete the app after I disconnected the device from the computer?